# Remove default <a> tags around an attachment in Wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Everytime I attach an image to a post in WordPress, it is automatically wrapped in `<a>` tags. I'm aware you can change it in the admin settings, but can PHP or jQuery be used to **prevent** it happening in the first place?

Comment: jquery runs in the client so it won't help you "prevent" anything

Comment: Could this be achieved with PHP?

Comment: If you can change it in the admin settings, that would be the cleanest way to turn it off. Why would you want to do it with PHP or jQuery? jQuery is browser side script not server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_media_link( $form_fields, $post ) {

        unset( $form_fields['url'] );

              return $form_fields;

}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'remove_media_link', 10, 2 );
```

Try this.

You can refer this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33724/remove-links-from-images-using-functions-php)